# Skilled Worker Visa: Teaching Assistant

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, salary

I want to be a teaching assistant in the UK and therefore apply for the Skilled Worker Visa in the UK. Does anyone know how much I would have to earn if I am at the start of my career and under 26 to qualify for this visa? Or does anyone have experience with this visa in general? I want to work part-time, so can I pro-rate it to the salary of a 39-hour week?

Comment: The information you need is available here https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/when-you-can-be-paid-less  If you are contracted to work fewer hours, you need to make sure you still meet the salary requirement on a pro-rata basis